# Unable to transfer click event from one element to another in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, click, dom-events

The following code works perfectly on Chrome, Safari and Opera but on Mozilla Firefox.

```
$("#first").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#second").click();
    return false;
});
<form action="http://jsfiddle.net">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Bing" id="first">
</form>

<form action="http://example.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to adams" id="second">
</form>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5GRVb/

**[Resolved]:** Thanks @ **C-lin**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to pass the parameter event within the function:

```
$("#first").click(function(event){
\\    ---------     here    ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use event.preventDefault() together with the return false. This will work.

```
$("#first").click(function(){
    $("#second").click(); 
    return false;
});
```